# Using a pl-sql procedure to select best team from players database

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am using oracle SQL developer 11g. I have a database of 100 football players. I have a table called **PROFILE_PLAYERS** which has following columns:

```
player_id, player_name, attack_skill(number),
defense_skill(number), passing_skill(number), GK_skill(number)
```

Now, I want to form a team of 11 players which contains 3 best attackers (highest attack_skill), 4 best midfielders (highest passing_skill), 3 best defenders (best defense_skill) and 1 best GK (best GK_skill).

I want to write a procedure which displays the 11 best players with their player_name and player_id.

Can I use  the rank() here? Should I use for loop with a counter in the procedure?

Comment: This can all be done in a single SQL statement; you do not need to use PL/SQL at all. Now you know that, how close do you think you can get trying it for yourself? You think you ought to use `rank()`, have you attempted it? Do you get the results you want? If not, _why_? That is the question you should constantly be asking yourself, _why_? It's also the question you should constantly ask others if you don't understand their explanation of something. You'll never understand and be able to undertake any programming task yourself otherwise.

Comment: this is an interesting question. i think you have to define an order for evaluating the skills. for exmaple , if a no.1 attacker is also no.1 defender - what do you consider him to be ? as @Ben said, rank function is what you are looking for.

Comment: @haki, I did not say that the `rank()` function was what the OP was looking for, I don't think it is as it has gaps in the sequence. You, theoretically, don't need to use an analytic function at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ignore that the same player could be selected more than once due to different skills, the query could look like this:

```
select player_id, player_name
from (
    select player_id, player_name,
        rank() over(order by attack_skill desc) attack_rank,
        rank() over(order by defense_skill desc) defense_rank,
        rank() over(order by passing_skill desc) passing_rank,
        rank() over(order by gk_skill desc) gk_rank
    from profile_players
)
where attack_rank <= 3 or defense_rank <= 4
   or passing_rank <= 3 or gk_rank <= 1;
```

To be sure that you get exactly 11 players, you have to apply a few tricks:

```
select player_id, player_name
from (
    select player_id, player_name,
        least((attack_rank - 1) / 3, (defense_rank - 1) / 4,
            (passing_rank - 1) / 3, gk_rank - 1) blended_rank
    from (
        select player_id, player_name,
            rank() over(order by attack_skill desc) attack_rank,
            rank() over(order by defense_skill desc) defense_rank,
            rank() over(order by passing_skill desc) passing_rank,
            rank() over(order by gk_skill desc) gk_rank
        from profile_players
    )
    order by blended_rank desc
)
where rownum <= 11;
```

You can then wrap this query into a stored procedure if you really need to have a procedure.

Comment: probably you should use dense_rank instead of rank - it will let you avoid rownum tricks.

Comment: If there are 20 players, all having exactly the same skills, dense_rank won't help.